# How do you customize the material UI select component?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI select component that I need to customize. I am rendering it on a dark background and there I need the outline and all its contents to be light colors (i.e. grey and white).

[image]

I have managed to get the outline and the text contents to be light colors but I cannot figure out how to change the colors of the down and up arrows that you click on to open and close the select options. If you look at the screenshot I shared, you can barely even see the up arrow because it is black. How would I go about changing the color of that to grey or white?

This is what I have now:

```
<Select
    variant="outlined"
    sx={{
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    marginRight: 15,
    border: "1px solid darkgrey",
    color: "#fff",
    }}
    value={currency}
    onChange={(e) => setCurrency(e.target.value)}
>
    <MenuItem value={"USD"}>USD</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"INR"}>INR</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I ended up changing the color of the arrow icon.

```
<Select
    variant="outlined"
    sx={{
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    marginRight: 15,
    border: "1px solid darkgrey",
    color: "#fff",
    "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
        color: "white",
    },
    }}
    value={currency}
    onChange={(e) => setCurrency(e.target.value)}
>
    <MenuItem value={"USD"}>USD</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"INR"}>INR</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `icon` [css class](https://mui.com/api/select/#css) from the select (or `iconOutlined` in your case).

<strike>Like for example with `makeStyle`</strike>.
Outdated for material-ui 5, see comment and the other answer.

```
// outside the component
const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    iconClassName: {
      fill: "red",
    },
  })
);

...

// later in the component
const classes = useStyles();

<Select 
  classes={{ iconOutlined: classes.iconClassName }}
/>
```

Another option is to use the `IconComponent` [props](https://mui.com/api/select/#props) an completely replace the icon:

```
<Select 
  IconComponent={<YourComponentHere />}
/>
```

Comment: Hey I'm not using makeStyles in this way because this is the outdated way of MUI component styling according to the MUI 5 docs. Now, they recommend that developers use a combination of styled components and the sx prop. I ended using the sx prop and just adding this code: "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
        color: "white",
    },